# login page using ajax and php and set a session but i am not getting the value of the session after successful login on another php page in server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../rncdemo/w3.css">
        <script src="../rncdemo/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        include('menubar.php');
        ?>
        <center>
        <div class="w3-dark-grey" style="max-width:650px">
        <header class="w3-padding-32 w3-teal"><h4>Member Login</h4></header>
        <br><br>
        <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <div id="req"></div>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><label><b>User Name</b></label></td>
        <td><input class ="w3-input w3-border" type="text" id="username" name="username" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <td><label><b>Password</b></label></td>
        <td><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td><td class="w3-center">
        <br>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input class ="w3-btn w3-teal w3-hover-red" name="login" type="submit" id="login" value="Login">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class ="w3-btn w3-light-grey w3-hover-red" name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <br><br>
        <div id="errmsg"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </center>
        <script src="memlogin.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>

        ///////////

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#pwd").focus(function(){
                $("#errmsg").html('');
            });
            $("#login").click(function(){
                username = $("#username").val();
                pwd = $("#pwd").val();
                if(username=='' || pwd =='')
                {
                    $("#req").html("All fields are required");
                }
                else{
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "memlogprocess.php",
                    data: "username="+username+"&pwd="+pwd,
                   success: function(data){    
                    if(data=="ok")    {
                     window.location="memberwelcome.php";

                    }
                    else{
                         $("#errmsg").html("username or password is incorrect !!!!");
                         $("#pwd").val('');
                    }
                   }
                   /*beforeSend:function()
                   {
                    $("#msg").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                    $("#msg").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
                   }*/
                  });

                return false;
                }


            });


        });
```

///////////////

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        include('database.php');
        $name=$_POST['username'];
        $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];


        $rs=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from memberuser where username='$name' and password='$pwd'")or die("Could Not Perform the Query");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['memusername']=$name;
            echo 'ok';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'notok';
        }

        ?>
```

////////

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['memusername'];
    ?>
```

I am not getting the value of session value on welcome page on server But getting the value on localhost server. 1st time is not showing but after that it is showing the session value. PLZ help me......

Comment: where is your insert query?? you can't access from database using $_session[' '], you need to fetch using $row[' '].

Comment: amit sinha   did you tried what i addressed?

Comment: @amit did you tried..as i said you can't fetch databse data witout using $row[''];

Comment: @amit do you still need help??

Comment: why should i need insert query?? the objective is only take the username and password form user and check the them if success set session and go to  welcome page and print session value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is correct. If we face this kind of problem we need to change the file name.On the server if we edit a single file many time, there may be a chance to get this kind of error. So we need to change the file name and write the same code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to start session in all pages

```
 <?php session_start();?>
```

Note :- Start session on top of the page right after php tag

Comment: it is not useful.I am not understanding why the session value is not print on last (welcome page).Some browser like chrome show the value after 2 or more attempt but some browser like opera mini never show the value while session is successfully set.